# WCF webhttp service using JSON increasing message size

Tags: wcf, json, maxreceivedmessagesize

I'm using ASIFormDataRequest to POST an image in JSON format to a WCF REST service based on the **"WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)"**. It works fine for images smaller than the default message size of the WCF service @65536 bytes, but I want to increase that value.

All the examples I've seen have added a **webHttpBinding** with a higher maxReceivedMessageSize etc, together with a **service endpoint** using that bindingConfiguration. However, with this template there's no .svc or interface that I can point to in the endpoint tag.

EDIT: Sorry, I was able to fix it using the **standardEndpoint** tag:

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" maxBufferPoolSize="1500000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1500000" transferMode="Streamed" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I've maxed out every message size setting I can find, and I'm still running into the same problem. I'm suspicious that my service is not even using these settings for some reason. Sure could use some help. Thanks! Here's my "standardEndpoint":

```
 <standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="WebHTTP" maxBufferSize="2147483647"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="0" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true">
      <readerQuotas maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"  maxDepth ="2147483647" />
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Comment: Are you using the "WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)" template?

Comment: BrainMan, I resolved the same issue with the configuration you shared, starting with a "WCF REST Service Template 40(CS)" template.